# Regex if-else expression

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to extract the # of minutes from a text field using Oracle's `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function.

Data:

```
Treatment of PC7, PT1 on left. 15 min.
15 minutes.
15 minutes
15 mins.
15 mins
15 min.
15 min
15min
15
```

In each case, I'm hoping to extract the '15' part of the string.

Attempts:

- `\d+` gets all of the numeric values, including the '7' and '1', which is undesirable.
- `(\d)+(?=\ ?min)` get the '15' from all rows except the last.
- `(?((\d)+(?=\ ?min))((\d)+(?=\ ?min))|\d+)`, a conditional statement, doesnt' match anything.

What is wrong with my conditional statement?

** EDIT **

```
WITH DATA AS (

  SELECT 'Treatment of PC7, PT1 on left. 15 min.' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15 minutes.' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15 minutes' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15 mins.' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15 mins' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15 min.' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15 min' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15min' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT '15' COMMENTS FROM DUAL

)

SELECT  COMMENTS,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENTS, '(\d+)\s?(?:min.*)?$', 1, 1) A,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENTS, '\d+?(?= ?min)|^\d+$', 1, 1) B,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENTS, '\d+?(?: ?min)|^\d+$', 1, 1) C

FROM DATA
```

Results (there must be a better way to format columns than as 'code sample'):

```
COMMENTS A B C
Treatment of PC7, PT1 on left. 15 min.          
15 minutes.         
15 minutes          
15 mins.            
15 mins         
15 min.         
15 min          
15min           
15  15  15  15
```

Comment: I don't see any if-else statement.  Show us actual code, not a summary.

Comment: Do Oracle's regexp functions even support the conditional construction?

Comment: @AndyLester, the last bullet point is the 'if-else' expression, at least according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html.

Comment: @Xophmeister: I'll need to research that.  Based on Aust's answer, it may not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Regex will work for you.

```
^.*?(\d+)(( ?min.*$)|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*?` - matches the beginning of the string, followed by any character 0 or more times
- `(\d+)` - matches at least one digit and stores it in backreference position 1
- `( ?min.*$)` - matches a space (maybe), `min`, any character (maybe), then the end of the string.
- `(...|$)` - if it can't find `min`, it will see if there is the end of the string instead.

Then instead of using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` like this, replacing the entire string with what was stored in backreference position 1 (your number):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(COMMENTS, '^.*?(\d+)(( ?min.*$)|$)', '\1') A
```

Comment: I tried your expression on http://regexpal.com; it worked on all cases but the last '15'.  Oracle didn't like the expression at all.

Comment: @craig - I was under the impression that the string would only be one of those at a time. So if the tested string is only `15` it matches that. Are you trying to match all of it at once?

Comment: Yes, it will only be one of these.  I correct my testing, and it works on regexpal.  I'll have to research if Oracle supports conditionals.

Comment: @craig - Ok, I'm pretty sure they do. If you look here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm the first example they give is `(f|ht)tps?:`

Comment: Apparently POSIX ERE regexp is supported in Oracle: So `?` as a quantifier is fine, but it won't do things like lookaround assertions, which is probably why @Aust's regexp isn't working for you.

Comment: @Xophmeister - Hmm that's good to know. I'll just make the group non-capturing then... and research to make sure it supports that haha. Ok I am sure non-capturing is supported.

Comment: Please review the results of my testing on Oracle 10g.

Comment: It appears that Oracle's regular expression engine does NOT support look-ahead assertions, so your answer won't work.

Comment: @Aust - `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` only has 5 arguments in 10g; you've listed 6: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

Comment: @craig - Yes I realized that after posting and gave you another solution. Using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` see if that works.

Comment: @Aust - Nope.  Is there a way to feed the results of one regex into another? `(\d+)( ?min|$)` would feed `\d+`, but without using the two `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` calls as I have done?

Comment: @craig - What was the result when you used `REGEXP_REPLACE()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19174/discussion-between-craig-and-aust)

Comment: I don't think that the `^.*?` part is necessary, except in replace.

Comment: @BradGilbert - Since we're using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` it is necessary to make sure the entire text field is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the timestamp will always appear as the last part of the string, this works:

```
(\d+)\s?(?:min.*)?$
```

I don't know if Oracle supports non-capturing groups, but that's easily worked around. My experience is that it's RegExp engine is limited to quite vanilla stuff.

Comment: +1 - I agree. If it is guaranteed that the timestamp is at the end, this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate, working solution that employs multiple expressions:

```
TO_NUMBER(
    CASE
        -- number only
        WHEN LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_COMMENT, '^\d+$', 1, 1) ) >0 THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_COMMENT, '^\d+$', 1, 1)
        -- XX min
        WHEN LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_COMMENT, '\d+( ?min)', 1, 1) ) >0 THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_COMMENT, '\d+( ?min)', 1, 1), '\d+', 1, 1)
    END
) MINUTES
```

** edit **

```
-- same results without the `CASE` statement:
TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(COMMENTS, '(\d+)( ?min|$)', 1, 1), '\d+', 1, 1) )
```